# A Question on the Rate of Change of the Arc-Length

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, intuition, parametrization, arc-length

**Main Question**

Consider some curve $y(x)$, going from a point $(x_0,y_0)$ to a point $(x_1,y_1)$.

Let $L$ be the length of the curve, and the function $F$ be the rate of change of the length of this curve with respect to $x$.

$$\frac{d L}{d x}=F=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{d y}{d x}\right)^{2}}$$

This is well demonstrated in the image below:

[image]

The arc-length of the entire curve would therefor be given by:

$$\int_{x_0}^{x_1}{F}dx$$

At each $(x,y)$ along the curve, the curve has a slope of $y'(x)$. Consider the derivative: $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y^{\prime}(x)}$$

This derivative tells us how the rate of growth of the length of our curve with respect to $x$ changes with respect to slope of our function at any point. How $F=\frac{dL}{dx}$ changes with respect to $y'(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}$.

If we evaluate the derivative, we get:

$$\frac{d F}{d y^{\prime}(x)}=\frac{d}{d\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)}(\sqrt{\left(1+(d y / d x)^{2}\right)})=\frac{(d y / d x)}{\sqrt{1+(d y / d x)^{2}}}=\frac{d y / d x}{dL / dx}=\frac{d y}{d L}$$

This is saying that the rate of change of the rate of change of the path-length with respect to $x$ all with respect to the slope of our function is equal to the rate of change of $y$ with respect to the arc-length.

***Why?***

This MUST have an intuitive explanation! But, although I've tried and tried, I haven't been able to understand it.

---

**Additional Notes:**

If in the the picture above, let the bottom-most left angle of the infinitesimal triangle be $\theta$. Then, the expression for $\frac{d F}{d y^{\prime}(x)}$ can be rewritten as:

$$\frac{d}{d\left(y^{\prime}(x)\right)}(\sqrt{\left(1+(\tan(\theta))^{2}\right)})=\frac{(\tan(\theta))}{\sqrt{1+(\tan(\theta))^{2}}}=\frac{\tan(\theta)}{\sec(\theta)}=\sin(\theta)$$

Sure enough, $\sin(\theta)$ is the rate of change of $y$ with respect to the arc-length. However, this didn't help me understand the result.

Additionally, I would think that if I wanted to get the rate of change of $F$ with respect to $y'(x)$, I could simply divide one by the other, which would give me...

$$\frac{d}{dy^{\prime}(x)}\left(\frac{dL}{dx}\right)=\frac{d L}{dx} \div \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dL}{dy}.$$

...the reciprocal of what regular'ol differentiation does. Why?

I appreciate all and any help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Duplicate question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3729521/intuition-for-the-derivatives-in-the-lagrangian-derivation-for-the-planar-geodes.  Please @joshua, edit your former question with this new information.  Do not ask the same question twice.  And please, as exhibited in your former question, refrain from using emoticons in your posts on math.se.  They are fine to use in text messages, but not here.

Comment: @amWhy all fixed! You're right, I should've deleted it before posting this one. I'm sorry. I've deleted it.

Comment: That's not okay to do.  To post a question, reask it, even if you had previously deleted the former post.  I've flagged for moderator attention.  It is not okay to double post a question.  There was nothing stopping you from taking time to edit your original question.  Do not ask the same question twice, when you should have edited the first.   I'd suggest you delete this post, edit the former post, and undelete the former post.

Comment: @amWhy Oh, I understand - I agree with you. But in this case there was more to it. The problem was that in my old question, I went on a huge side-track and my question ended up being about something entirely different than what I started with (arc-length vs geodesics). I thought it would be a good idea to ask a new question, link it in the old one, and then delete it a few days after so people that were gonna answer on the old one would answer on this one instead (since this one was more concise and to the point). - But, if you prefer I can delete this one and undelete and edit the old one?

Comment: No worries.  Thanks for the explanation.  I understand, @joshua.:-)

Comment: @amWhy all good! I understand why you got bothered by me double-asking as well. All that being said, interestingly enough that long sidetracked question got two up-votes and one favorite, while this one has a down-vote! I guess people must've liked the side-tracking better ! Anyways, if you could help me out with it, I'd really appreciate your answer. I'm quite confused! Thank you.

Comment: First major warning: You cannot manipulate *partial derivative* symbols the way you can ordinary symbols. In particular, if $(u,v) = f(x,y)$ and $g(u,v) =(x,y)$, it is almost never the case that $\partial u/\partial x = \dfrac1{\partial x/\partial u}$. Note that totally different variables are being held fixed on the two sides of the equation. So, in particular, your equation $$\frac{dy/dx}{\partial L/\partial x} = \frac{dy}{dL}$$ is just nonsense. With $F=F(x,y,y')$, the  valid equation is just  $\partial F/\partial y' = y'/F(x,y,y')$.

Comment: @TedShifrin yep that makes sense, since if the function $F(x,y,z)$ has multiple parameters as its inputs, the total derivative with respect to $x$ will not be the same as its explicit derivative with respect to $x$ (we need to apply chain-rule with the other variables, since they may depend on $x$ as well, and get $dF/dx + dF/dy * dy/dx + dF/dz * dz/dx$). However, in this case specifically, the problem is actually with the partials...I shouldn't have used them. I should've used $d$ for all of them, since $F$ is solely a function of $y'(x)$, so that $dL/dx=F$, no partials. I'm fixing that now!

Comment: No, actually, you have to think of $F$ as a function of the variable $y'$, not as a (composed) function of $x$. Ordinarily, when you do calculus of variations, the functional is given by integrating a function $F(x,y,y')$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm a little confused...ok, I know you love giving hints instead of straight up answers (and I actually appreciate that quite a bit) but, in this case...could we maybe talk more about this in a chat? I think I'm confused beyond saving with hints on this one...I don't know how to move this to chat though!